# Vue.js how to fetch webpage in the same server (in html with custom js, css and pictures) and display it

Tags: vue.js, architecture, backend, vue-router, blogs

First of all, thank you for your help.

I'm currently writting a blog in vue.js with **vuejs-cli** and I'm stuck on a problem about the architecture of my blog.

---

What I want to do:

I want my vue.js app to fetch an article (which is a whole webpage with .html,.js,.css and pictures) in the subfolder of the "Articles" folder and then display it in a vue in two ways:

- like a preview (an image from the article and the article's title)
- by diplaying the full article

So I want the file tree to look like this:

```
Root
|
|-dist of my blog
|
|-Articles
    |-Article1
    |    |-index.html
    |    |-style.css
    |    |-script.js
    |    |-img
    |       |-img1.png
    |       |-img2.png
    |
    |-Article2
         |...
```

- **I don't want to rebuild my app (for exemple, modifying by hand the router) each time i add a new article.** Because I won't be able to do it when I'll feed this blog.
- **I don't want to use a cms or markdown**

What I tried:

- building an api with nodejs as a backend of my blog to get an article, but it seems really difficult to transmit pictures. Also, I'm really not sure if it's a good idea to go on this way. (at this moment, i'm able to get the title/description and the body of an article with ajax and my app in nodejs but not the pictures, the style and the script)

Do you have any idea or tips about how to achieve this ?
(I don't want a code, I'm searching a way to accomplish this)

Once again, thank you for your precious help ! :)

---

EDIT:

**I didn't try it**

May be it is a good solution to add my article in [the *public folder* of vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder) and fetch them in a vue with [HTML *ifram*](http://%20https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/html-iframes.php) and program a backend to give link to these articles thanks to a database.

Three question for this solution:

- Can I load/modify articles in the public folder after build ?
- Will the public folder be cleaned after build ?
- Is fetching image/js from the html page in the public folder the same as for a "normal" website ?

Comment: Will it be possible for you to keep the articles listed in a database or data file, such as a JSON file at `/Articles/index.json`, as they are added? Or will your app need to go solely off the list of subdirectories of the `Articles` directory?

Comment: There is no problems to doing it, I could run a Cron job on my server to complete this database every hour.

Comment: This is more or less what I'm currently doing with the API I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it works !

---

**This is how I did it:**

1. I put my `Article` folder in the `public` folder of vue-cli
2. Created a nodejs programme to make/update a database of all articles in the `article` folder every 10 minutes, sorting them by date of creation (I will make a cron job with [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) later)
3. Made this nodejs programm to answer to some `GET` query:

   - when I want a preview, the programm send a "preview" of the article (it takes the title, the description and the first image of the html file of the `article` and send it in a html format)
   - when I want a url, the programm send the link of the html page inside the `public` folder (see how to do it [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder))
4. So on my vuejs app, the view fetch a preview to the nodejs backend with the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and show it. Then, when the user click on the preview, my vue show a `ifram` of the webpage's article at the specified url fetched.

**Tips**: Be aware that `npm build` will erase the `Article`'s folder if it's only present in the dist folder. To avoid it, change the script of `package.json` to add the [`--no-clean` argument](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-build) to the build command

---

I don't know if it's a good and efficient way of doing it, but it works well and it's very easely customisable. So for the moment, I'll do it like that way :)